# installing reactive banana-wx or wx on redhat based linux with ghc 7.0.4

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp

hi i'm trying to install, (without having to update or install the latest compiler),reactive-banana-wx and one of the requirement's are failing

```
cabal install reactive-banana-wx
```

and heres the error

```
Configuring wxc-0.90.0.4...
setup: failed
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
reactive-banana-wx-0.6.0.1 depends on wxc-0.90.0.4 which failed to install.
wx-0.90.0.1 depends on wxc-0.90.0.4 which failed to install.
wxc-0.90.0.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
wxcore-0.90.0.3 depends on wxc-0.90.0.4 which failed to install
```

when i try to cabal install wxcore ,wx or wxc they all say failed and point towards wxc being required.

here's the error

```
cabal install wxc
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/wxc-0.90.0.419410/wxc-0.90.0.4/Setup.hs, /tmp/wxc-0.90.0.419410/wxc-0.90.0.4/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/wxc-0.90.0.419410/wxc-0.90.0.4/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring wxc-0.90.0.4...
setup: failed
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
wxc-0.90.0.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

here's my compiler info if it would be useful

```
ghc -v
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.0.4, for Haskell 98, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.0.4
```

Comment: When you get an `ExitFailure 1`, there is often some other error message earlier on in the output. If there is, could you post it here? You could also just put *all* your output on [hpaste](http://hpaste.org/).

Comment: http://hpaste.org/72291 , in summary i tried cabal install wxc -v to produce more error messages . and it said there were many packages missing , i tried to install one named lhc and it failed similarly

Comment: You don't want `lhc` at this point, it is another Haskell compiler. I suspect you don't have the development libraries for WxWindows installed though the output from Cabal doesn't say either way.

Comment: The cabal output can be... deceiving. Apart from checking that you have the development libraries (`*-dev` or `*-devel` packages), make sure you also have g++. I didn't have g++ when trying to build some wx and I got some completely unrelated error message (but not the one you're getting).

Comment: @TikhonJelvis g++ is there i use it all the time , it's version 4.7.0

Comment: Building `wxc` failed on hackage too. Not clear what it's about, probably best to ask on the wx (haskell) mailing list.

Comment: @pyCthon: It looks like you don't have the development libraries for wxWidgets 2.9.3 installed. Without these, the `wxc` package cannot be installed.

Comment: nope there installed, and oddly enough i recently bought a mac book pro laptop and the same error occurs with it , wxWidgets are installed on both via repository on fedora and via mac ports  on mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the same error trying to install phooey with ghc 7.4.1 on Debian tonight. The reason is a bug in the package wxc-0.90.0.4 and it should affect all wxHaskell-based packages. You can fix it, there is no need to downgrade your wxc package...

The easiest way to reproduce it is to do

```
cabal install wxc
```

or

```
cabal install glade
```

It might be a good idea to make sure that all prerequisites are in place, before you do it. wxc depends on a number of cabal and Linux packages and all of them should be installed and compiled... I did it in the most stupid way possible, just by running

```
cabal install wxc
```

and reading error messages which it spills out. This sweetie usually tells you what it wants... For instance, if it complains about cabal package `x`, just do cabal install `x`. If it complains about Linux package `y`, then use your Linux package manager and install the development version of this package, which is called normally `lib<y>-dev` in Debian. So, for instance, if

```
cabal install wxc
```

gives you an error saying that package gtk+2.0 is missing, you want to do

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

The same story with cairo, glade2 and other GTK-related libraries

When you are green with all prerequisites, you want to install wxWidgets-2.9, which is currently in the Development stage... so, it doesn't have any binaries for Linux and you should build it yourself. Download the source code from wxWidgets website and build it. It is pretty easy to do, just:

- untar/unzip the source code to your favorite directory
- run ./config
- run ./make

If you are on wxc-0.90.0.4, at this moment you should encounter our little bug... To keep the long story short, it is in the file eljpen.cpp, which you can find in

```
~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/wxc/0.90.0.4/wxc-0.90.0.4.tar.gz
```

Open the archive, go to the line 159 in the file and replace *_ref = NULL; with _ref = NULL or anything else what makes more sense. Then recreate the archive in the same place with the fixed eljpen.cpp file in it.

- run ./make

It should work now.

- run sudo make install (normally, you should have root privileges to insatll wxWidgets library...).

after it is done try to do

```
cabal install wx
```

again. It should be working now. I guess, after that you can enjoy your reactive-banana-wx, wxHaskell, phooey, etc.

PS http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3576397&group_id=73133&atid=536845. Why didn't I find it earlier? :/

Answer (score 1):

I'v solved this problem on Lubuntu 12.10 so:

sudo cabal info wx

```
Synopsis:      wxHaskell
Versions available: 0.11.1.2, 0.12.1.4, 0.12.1.5, 0.12.1.6, 0.13.2,
                    0.13.2.1, 0.13.2.3, 0.90, 0.90.0.1 (and 11 others)
```

I picked out different versions of wxHaskell, but only 0.13.2.3 was right.

sudo cabal install wx-0.13.2.3

...and everything has compiled and installed. Then I could install:

sudo cabal install reactive-banana-wx -fbuildExamples

That's no depends on the version of your Glasgow Haskell Compiler or the sort of your Linux.